# Different already available yocto variables?

Tags: yocto

Where are the different yocto variables just like  ${ TOPDIR }?

I am looking for other known variables that I can use in my yocto for e.g. THISDIR.
What are the different variables available in yocto? I couldn't find them in the yocto documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In the mega manual, there is [a Chapter 33. Variables Glossar](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-variables-glossary) that "lists common variables used in the OpenEmbedded build system and gives an overview of their function and contents."

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to `poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf` configuration file.

This file must be know by anyone working with Yocto. It contains bunch of metadata arranged in several sections, including common used variables.